# Why can't I create links in /bin?

Tags: bash, macos, shebang, macos-mojave

I am using MacOs Mojave, and I figured that the `env` binary sits under `/usr/bin/env`. Now we have a bunch of shell scripts (written and working under linux) that have `/bin/env` hardcoded for the shebang line.

I thought a simple:

```
cd /bin
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/env env
```

or maybe

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/env .
```

should do the trick, but I get:

> ln: env: Operation not permitted

(same for `cp`).

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think you are suffering from **System Integrity Protection** https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899 The workaround is here https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: The lesson here is that shebangs aren't *supposed* to be portable between machines; they are a convenience for use on one machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you *could* go ahead and [disable](https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/) [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899), I do not recommend it.

Instead, change your shebangs to use `/usr/bin/env`; that's where `env` belongs.

Apparently some Linux distros contain `env` both in `/bin` and in `/usr/bin`, but some (including Debian and probably derivatives) don't. Neither does macOS, and I bet other BSDs don't, either.